# A Elements with HREF="#" causing page to reload on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `a` elements which run functions via **javascript** and have a `#` set as the `href` however I have changed something recently that causes these to try and reload the page rather than do nothing and so breaks their functionality.

What can i look for that could cause this?

```js
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function(){alert("do something javascript")};
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#">Do Some JS</a>

Clicking this however reloads page and am unsure what i have done to cause this to reload the page.
```

I can't reproduce in the snippet, if i did i wouldn't be asking the question but something is causing these links to reload the page which is not expected behaviour.

So far i can only think or a quick and dirty fix:

```
$('a[href="#"]')).click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I however would like to know what could be causing this issue to arise.

## The problem

Ok i found it thanks for your help:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state !== null) { 
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

That will do it for sure.

I think it's so that as pages are heavily reliant on ajax there was no way to go back to where you had been.

I figured the easiest way was have the urls update on ajax changes so when i clicked back the url would change to last action and then cause page to reload correctly on pop state change.

## My Quick Fix

I will change the code to:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state !== null) { 
    } else {
        if(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.length - 1) != "#") {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working snippet using `<>` and replicate your issue here?

Comment: Ill try but not sure what broke it.

Comment: maybe it is scrolling back to the top and not reloading like how # works...

Comment: check your browser console. There might be JS error.

Comment: No js errors i'm afraid.

Comment: @epascarello No its not scrolling im at the top of the page anyway. I can see the javascript fire and a popup appears but then dissapears as page reloads.

Answer (score 7):

This is normal behaviour of `a` tags if you don't want them to reload your page or scroll to top of your page you should remove `href` from your `a` tags.
 You can also stop them from reloading your page like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">No reload</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)">No reload</a>
```

Comment: Not normally if you have a # you can link elements on page by id.

Comment: @harri Yes if you are targeting `id` but if you are just using `#` it will reload page.

Comment: No it doesn't see snippet.

Comment: This is not a normal behavior of `a` tag. `#` will not allow page to reload.

Answer (score 3):

In your function you need to use `e.preventDefault()` or `event.preventDefault()`. So for example:

```
function clickMe(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

As per the most recent comment, you need to pass in the event to the function so it looks like this:

```
$('a[href="#"]')).click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Note that this is an approach I wouldn't recommend since it will block all links and could cause more problems than intended. You'll want to use a specific class to target your anchors.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted...? This is what OP needs to prevent default action on anchor tags...

Comment: Im not sure why this is a downvote, thanks for your help but i don't think this is default behaviour.

Comment: this is probably closest i have to a fix although not quite as you have done it. $('a[href="#"]')).click(function() {
  e.preventDefault();
});

Comment: Ok thank you I updated my answer but try $('a[href="#"]')).click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

Comment: To be honest yeah  i noticed that and changed it but it didn't work for a patch.

Comment: Also yeah its only targeting links that are a # which should do nothing anyway. but i have actually found my issue and am working on fixing the issue at the source now.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a onClick="callback();"></a>
```

just remove that href= "#"

It will not reload or refresh the browser

Answer (score -1):

try `javascript:void(0)` instead #

eg.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
```

because without seeing some code we never know what cause this problem.

Comment: Ive only foud two examples so far but im guessing there are 10s of these and modifying the whole template seems like a lot of work. Thanks for the suggestion tho.